# How to correctly use tf.scatter_nd using tf.argmax indices?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensor with a dynamic shape, X with shape = [? , ? , 256 , ?]
Then I'm computing:

```
argmax = tf.argmax(X, axis=3) # shape [ ?, ?, 256]
```

Then I want to compute Y with the same shape as X with ones where are the max, so I'm trying to do the following:

```
Y = tf.scatter_nd(tf.cast(argmax, tf.int32), tf.ones(tf.shape(argmax)), tf.shape(X))
```

But I'm getting the following error :

> ValueError: The inner -252 dimensions of output.shape=[?,?,?,?] must match the inner 1 dimensions of updates.shape=[?,?,256]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1 for 'ScatterNd' (op: 'ScatterNd') with input shapes: [?,?,256], [?,?,256], [4].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by doing the following:

```
Y = tf.one_hot(argmax, 2, 1.0, -1.0)
```